# Script Shell not return all output message

Tags: java, shell

I hace a shell script below that execute a verification call for Sophos Antivirus :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Check state of antivirus sophos

echo "Vérification de l'état de l'antivirus"
state=`${1}bin/savdstatus 2>&1`
successtate="Sophos Anti-Virus is active"
echo "Return message : " $state
if [ "$state" = "$successtate" ]; then
    exit 0
else
    exit 1
fi
```

If I call it from the shell, I can saw that the output is complete :

[image]

I use it in a Java class,

```
@Override
    public void checkAntivirusState() throws IOException {
        var processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
        // -- Linux -- Run a shell script
        processBuilder.command(pathToFileToExecute(), pathToSophosInstallationDir());
        var process = processBuilder.start();
        var output = new StringBuilder();
        try (var reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()))) {

            String line;
            output.append("Antivirus or on-access scanning is disabled!").append(Chars.LF);
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                output.append(line).append(Chars.LF);
            }

            int exitVal = process.waitFor();
            if (exitVal == 0) {
                LOGGER.info("Antivirus Enabled");
            } else {
                var errorMessage = output.toString().replaceAll("[\r\n]", "");
                LOGGER.error(errorMessage);
                throw new SecurityException(errorMessage);
            }
            process.destroy();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
```

pathToFileToExecute() and pathToSophosInstallationDir() return respectively the path to the script below and the installation directory of Sophos use by the shell script.

On the execution, state is not complete : only "Sophos Anti-Virus is active" is return and catch but not the on-access scanning part of the message.

I don't understand why... do you have an idea ?

**EDIT 1**

Java trace :

[image]

Comment: If you try to call a simple script (something that just outputs "hello" for example) with this code, do you get the "hello" back?

Comment: In the shell script, there is an "echo" command" wich display partial return message ... If I put "Hello", Hello is return .... I addes the log of Java execution

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved and was ultimately simple:

When I start the shell directly I was on root, but the application is using another user who is not authorized to run the test.

So I added my user to the sophosav group and it's OK.